# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded - Error with Post to Ruby API from Preact Frontend

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, api, preact

My browser ends up freezing and then giving me this error when I try to sign up. This is my first time working using a preact frontend with a rails api (also my first time posting on stackoverflow). Let me know if you need anymore information.

```
import { h, Component } from 'preact';
import $ from 'jquery';

class Signup extends Component {
    handleClick = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      // console.log(this.password.value)
       var firstName = this.first_name;
       var lastName = this.last_name;
       var userName = this.userName;
       var email = this.email;
       var password = this.password;

      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/users',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { user: { first_name: firstName, last_name: lastName, userName: userName, email: email, password: password } },
        success: (response) => {
          console.log('it worked!', response);
        },
        error: (response) => {
          console.log('it failed', response);
        }
        });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="sign-up">
            <br></br>
            <br/>
            <h2>Sign Up</h2>
            <br/>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleClick} method="get">
            <ul>
              <li> First name: <input ref={a => this.first_name = a} type="text" name="first_name"/> </li> <br/>
              <li> Last name: <input ref={b => this.last_name = b} type="text" name="last_name"/> </li> <br/>
              <li> Username: <input ref={ c => this.username = c} type="text" name="userName"/> </li> <br/>
              <li> Email: <input ref={d => this.email = d} type="text" name="email"/> </li> <br/>
              <li> Password: <input ref={e => this.password = e} type="password" name="password"/> </li> <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
            </ul>
            </form>
          </div>
          )
        }
}

export default Signup;
```

[Picture of Error coming from Chrome Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URPJT.png)

Comment: Have you ensured your api works as expected with a tool like postman?

Comment: You can get this error when you have an infinite loop. Make sure that you don't have any unending, recursive self references.

Comment: Alspo you are sending whole dom nodes with your code in handleClick. Try: `var firstName = this.first_name.value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing a bunch of code and using fetch instead of jquery. Check it out below. Thanks to everybody for your comments.

```
import { h, Component } from 'preact';
```

// import $ from 'jquery';
import axios from 'axios';

```
class Signup extends Component {
  handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = 'http://localhost:3000/users',
      data= JSON.stringify({
        user: {
          first_name: this.firstName.value,
          last_name: this.lastName.value,
          username: this.userName.value,
          email: this.email.value,
          password: this.password.value,
        }
      });

    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: data
    })
    .then( res => res.json())
    .then( jsonRes => window.location = "/login")
    .catch( err => console.log(err))
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="sign-up">
      <br></br>
      <br/>
      <h2>Sign Up</h2>
      <br/>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleClick} method="get">
      <ul>
        <li> First name: <input ref={a => this.firstName = a} type="text"/> </li> <br/>
        <li> Last name: <input ref={b => this.lastName = b} type="text"/> </li> <br/>
        <li> Username: <input ref={ c => this.userName = c} type="text"/> </li> <br/>
        <li> Email: <input ref={d => this.email = d} type="text"/> </li> <br/>
        <li> Password: <input ref={e => this.password = e} type="password"/> </li> <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
      </ul>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
}

export default Signup;
```